# Get return values from firebase functions?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get json from a firebase function request, here's what I'm trying:

```
export const listener = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    return {foo:"bar"}
})
```

unfortunately this yields a timeout with no result when I go to the appropriate url in chrome, I also tried:

```
function getDude(){
    return {dude:"dude"};
}

export const listener = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    return Promise.all([getDude()]);
})
```

Same result as before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTPS type functions don't return promises, so you should not declare them async.  (However, all of the other types of Cloud Functions *do* require that you return promises for any async work they perform.)

HTTPS type functions are obliged to return a result to the client in order to terminate the function.  This is as simple as using `res.send()`, or any of the methods described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  That's not to say you shouldn't be using promises in the function to wait for async work to complete - you just don't return one from the function.

Comment: Ah ok then how do I go about accomplishing what I want to?

Comment: As stated in my answer, send a response to the client with `res.send()`.  There's lots of sample code.  https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/